# fopen() and file_get_contents() are disabled, is there another way to write to a file?

Tags: php

I made a script that overwrites an xml file, and it works locally, but the hosting company does not allow fopen() or file_get_contents(). Is there another way, maybe with curl, to create / write to a file?

Comment: does it allow `system()` or similar type?

Comment: What OS on the server?

Comment: Try [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: system() seems available, ubuntu server, fwrite gets me a permission error

Comment: Get a different hosting company.

Comment: What are the file permissions of the directory you are writing too?

Comment: No choice on the hosting co. :( 665, its not a permissions issue.

Comment: Is SE Linux installed and enabled? What about SU PHP? Are you sure you are not hitting the others permission?

Comment: If you have no choice on the hosting company then you'll have to find a different way to store data or find out from the hosting company what they will and will not allow.

Comment: Contact your service provider and find out how you can write files, or maybe they can change your permissions

Answer (score 0):

As revealed in the comments the directory that is being written to has permissions set to `665`

In order to create a file in a directory it must have execute permissions.

```
$ mkdir test
$ chmod 665 test/
$ touch test/foo
touch: cannot touch ‘test/foo’: Permission denied
$ cd test/
bash: cd: test/: Permission denied
```

Modifying the permissions to 755 should do the trick.

```
chmod 755 test/
$ touch test/foo
$ cd test/
$ ls
foo
```

If you can ssh to the box and change the permissions your self then do so, else contact support and see if they can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you can use ftp protocol.
To get content onlyyiu can include and show.
If you want create or edit file use ftp protocol.
you don't must make all in php (i think) and you can use ajax or jquery to add this

The second way it's change permissions to your file (chmod). In console or via ftp client.
this can help you.

But in my opinion you must check and buy new hosting plan in oder company or if you don't can this check information about ftp/ajax/jQuery.